# Google Maps Geocoding API: Are Address Component Types independent of each other?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Maps API v3. If I want to determine the State of a US address in a geocoding result, do I test for both `administrative_area_level_1` AND `political`? Or can I just test for `administrative_area_level_1`? Will a result of `administrative_area_level_1` WITHOUT `political` ever occur, and if so, would that mean something OTHER than State?

Comment: I think it will be consistent within a country.  But  in other countries there are different systems.  Like Belgium has 3 regions, then 10 provinces.  UK is a country, made up of 4 (kind of) countries, each having provinces. There are cities who are countries (Singapore, Vatican, ...), So Google Maps just numbers these levels.

Comment: sounds like it would be consistent within countries, according to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)